# Python importing an array from a different file

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, function, import

So,I have a `main.py` and a `file.py`
on `file.py` I have a function(ex:

```
def s_break(message):
     words = message.split(" ")
```

, and an array `words`.   )

When I import the words array into `main.py` using: `from "filename" import words` I receive the array empty. Why?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to show more code I have no idea what are you doing and what could be the error

Comment: So, I have a function in file.py that splits a string in words, which are inserted in the array. Now, when I want to use that array in a different file, it comes empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually call the `s_break` function otherwise you'll just get the empty list/array.

*test_file.py:*

```
message = 'a sample string this represents'
list_of_words = []

def s_break(message):
    words = message.split(" ")
    for w in words:
        list_of_words.append(w)

s_break(message)    # call the function to populate the list
```

And then in *main.py*:

```
from test_file import list_of_words

print list_of_words
```

Output:

```
>>> ['a', 'sample', 'string', 'this', 'represents']
```

Comment: thank you!
It turned out I had to add at the parameter of s_break() the list_of_words array.